# Socket.io-client Failed to load resource

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I have this issue trying to connect to websocket using socket.io-client (Socket.IO.js build:0.9.16)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myserver.it/socket.io/1/?t=1488475368547. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my_vps_ip' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

the strange things are:

- localhost it works fine
- in amazon ec2 instance it works fine
- in another vps (cloud vps [bought here](http://www.register.it/server/virtual.html?chglng=eng)) it doesn't works

This is my code:

```
socket = io.connect('https://myserver.it' ,{
        transports: ['websocket'],
        secure: true,
        'force new connection' : false,
        'reconnect' : true,
    });
```

Apache 2.4.18 in twice VPS, same configuration, same modules

I really don't understand ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno if this help but I've faced with same kind of problem time ago.

Check your URL and ensure it NOT end with `/`

e.g. `https://myserver.it/`  !=   `https://myserver.it`

Comment: OH MY GOD THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've run into a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. You need to make sure that you are explicitly allowing access to the requested resource.

You may want to look at [enable-cors.org](https://enable-cors.org/index.html) former guidance.

Comment: You know what I have to do? I have tried to disabling cors with chrome plugin (for testing purpose) without success. And why with one server works and not with another?

Comment: Without more details on your specific code, I really can't help more. Take a look at the links in the answer.

Comment: thanks in advice, I add my js code and checked the link. I didn't think it's a server problem because in one vps it works fine